# Login and upload file using Python 'requests'

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I need to login and upload a file . The problem I am facing is, login page is different from uploading page. If I have to do it manually, I'll login (`login.php`) to the site and then navigate to the upload page (`uploader.php`) to upload the file. This what I have written:

```
import requests

url1='http://www.abc.com/login.php'
r = requests.post(url1, auth=('uname', 'pword'))
print r.status_code //msg:'200'

payload = {'upload':open('./tmp.txt')}
url2='http://www.abc.com/uploader.php'
r = requests.post(url2, data=payload)
print r.text //msg: "you must first login to upload the file"
```

My code is obviously not working as expected. Login part is working correctly but not uploading part.
Please how can I accomplish my goal.

**UPDATE:**

To give more insight into my question, I am giving `login.php` and `uploader.php` file details:

**login.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php" class="login">
<input type="text" name="username"></input>
<input type="password" name="password"></input>        
<input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
```

**uploader.php**

```
<form action='uploader.php' method='POST' id='form' class='upload' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type='file' name='upload' id='file'></input>
<input type='button' value='Analyze' name='button' onclick='javascript: checkuploadform(false)'>
```

Comment: Where is the code you said you were going to post?

Comment: I have already posted it. why is it not visible?

Comment: Hey, you're doing a get requests to login.php when it should be post, according to above html.

Comment: Updated answer for some changes

Comment: yes, its `post`, I have edited it in the question. but still I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Please post the what the `.content` of the request `r` is. Maybe it's not really logging in and just returning a error page which is fetched  by the request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a session and then use that session to do your requests -

```
sessionObj = requests.session()
sessionOj.get(...) # Do whatever ...
```

A session persists your cookies for future requests.
And use post parameters for username,password as the parameters are required to login in `login.php` , not auth username password.
Also use `files` parameter to upload files.
So the final code is -

```
import requests

sessionObj = requests.session()
url1='http://www.abc.com/login.php'
r = sessionObj.post(url1, params={'username':'usernamehere' , 'password':'password here'})
print r.status_code //msg:'200'


filehandle = open('./tmp.txt')
url2='http://www.abc.com/uploader.php'
r = sessionObj.post(url2, data={},files = {'upload':filehandle})
print r.text
```

[Docs.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but, I am still getting that error. I have updated the question to give more insight into `login.php` and `uploader.php`